# Integral of $ g(x)=\{x-\theta\}+\theta-1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Consider this function:
>
> $\theta \in [0,1]$
>   \begin{align}g
> (x)=\{x\}-\begin{cases}
> 0, & \mbox{ if }(\{x\}<\theta)\\1, & \mbox{ if }(\{x\}\geqslant \theta)\end{cases}=\{x-\theta\}+\theta-1\end{align}
>
> Compute $\int_0^1 g(x)dx$.

*$\{\}$ denotes fractional*

I know the solution is $\theta-\frac{1}{2}$. However when I break the integral into the two domain regions of the indicative function I get $-\theta$.

**Question**:

How shall I compute the integral?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use the first form of $g(x)$ and I get $\theta-\frac{1}{2}$. Please show what you did, so we might find the mistake

Comment: Use the first form and notice that $x\in(0,1)\implies \{x\}=x$ and break it to $\int_0^\theta+\int_\theta^1$

Comment: $\{x\}=x\space \forall \space x\in[0,1);\space\space$$\int_{0}^{\theta}{x}\space dx+\int_{\theta}^1(x-1)\space dx=\theta-1/2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Definition**

Using the first definition of $g(x)$, note that for $x\in[0,1)$, we have $\{x\}=x$. Thus, $$\int_0^1g(x)\,dx=\int_0^\theta g(x)\,dx+\int_\theta^1g(x)\,dx.$$ In the first integral, plug in $g(x)=x$, and in the second integral, we have $g(x)=x-1$. Evaluating these integrals yields $$\int_0^1g(x)\,dx=\theta-\frac12.$$

**Second Definition**

Using the second definition of $g(x)$, we have $$\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx=\int_0^1\{x-\theta\}+\theta-1\,dx=\int_0^1\{x-\theta\}\,dx+\theta-1.$$ To calculate this latter integral, observe that for $x\in[0,\theta)$, we have $$\{x-\theta\}=(x-\theta)-\lfloor x-\theta\rfloor=x-\theta-(-1)=1+x-\theta.$$ Similarly, for $x\in[\theta,1]$, we have $\{x-\theta\}=x-\theta$. So, splitting up the integral, we have $$\int_0^1\{x-\theta\}\,dx=\int_0^\theta 1+x-\theta\,dx+\int_\theta^1 x-\theta\,dx.$$ After evaluating these integrals and simplifying, we're left with $\frac12$. Adding this to the $\theta-1$ above, we have $$\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx=\theta-\frac12$$which matches the calculations above.

Answer (score 2):

Using $U(x)$ to denote the unit step function one may rewrite $g(x)$ as

$$ g(x)=x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor -U(x-\theta) $$

Then we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1g(x)\,dx&=&\int_0^1x\,dx-\int_0^1\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\,dx-\int_\theta^1\,dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}-(1-\theta)\\
&=&\theta-\frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray}